# Delphi 7 x64 registro

Tags: delphi

Testei em uma maquina Windows 8 o seguinte: inseri uma chave registro do Windows para inicialização. No Windows XP e Windows 7 que eram 32 bits funcionaram mas no Windows 8 que é 64 bits não funcionou. Alguém pode me dar uma ajudinha? Como inserir uma chave de registro no Windows 8 - 64 bits? Abaixo está o código que tentei.

```
var
Reg: TRegistry;
S: string;

begin
Reg := TRegistry.Create;
S:= variavelcontendocaminhoearqv;
Reg.rootkey:=HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
Reg.Openkey('software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\run\',true);
Reg.WriteString('programtest',S);
Reg.closekey;
Reg.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Acabei de testar agora e infelizmente não funcionou e nessa parte aqui Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE OR KEY_WOW64_64KEY); da erro não deixando compilar :p ... ta fod# ja tentei de tudo...

Comment: Qual erro aparece? outra coisa, como você chamou a *procedure* `inicializarPrograma`?

Comment: Sim chamei corretamente... ao compilar da erro: undeclared identifier: KEY_WOW64_64KEY

Comment: Atualizei a resposta novamente, teste daquele jeito e veja se o programa é colocado na inicialização, vá no Executar (Tecla do Windows + `R` e digite: `msconfig`)

Comment: agora já era :( estava testando na maquina da minha irmã ela foi embora agora lasco kkk ... se alguem puder da uma força de testar e ver se funciona e dizer ficaria muito grato ...

Comment: Bom, pelo menos no Windows 7 funcionou. Em teoria era para funcionar também no Windows 8, uma coisa que você deve se lembrar é do [UAC](http://windows.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/turn-user-account-control-on-off)! Uma coisa fora do contexto: Você pode votar nas *perguntas* e *respostas* que lhe foram uteis, seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade.

Comment: o win7 que você testou é 64bits?  ... ok votarei na sua com certeza!

Comment: Ok muito obrigado amigo, caso você consiga testar no 8 avise aqui ou se eu conseguir te aviso assim ficamos adiantados e informados das coisas que funcionam rsrs.

Comment: qmechanik faça um teste assim pegue o codigo que eu estava usando que citei acima e use ver se ele consegui inserir no seu win7 64 bits

Comment: O problema é que não há o `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` no seu código, isso é necessário em 64-bits.. Ideia: Porque não testa numa **máquina virtual**?

Comment: Bom se aquele cod não funcionar ja é 80% de certeza desse codigo funcionar no win8 rsrs, infelizmente não tenho pc de 64 bits

Comment: Maycon, quando puder testar para confirmar, dê um *feedback*!

Answer (score 4):

Talvez seja necessário passar o valor [`KEY_WOW64_64KEY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) no construtor.

```
// Uses Registry;
procedure inicializarPrograma(App, Caminho: string);
const 
  KEY_WOW64_64KEY = $0100; 
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE OR KEY_WOW64_64KEY); //
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    if Reg.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run', True) then
     Reg.WriteString(App, Caminho);
    Reg.CloseKey;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Exemplo de utilização:

```
inicializarPrograma(Caption, ParamStr(0));
```